# How to check if a 2D array is diagonally dominant in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hey guys i want to make a function which checks a 2D array whether is diagonallydominant or not

Any Ideas??

I have managed to find the diagonall but how to check if diagonally dominant??

```
public static int arraySum(int[][] array){
    int total = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
    {

        total += array[row][row];
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: add up the other values and see if the diagonal value is bigger than the other values' sums

Comment: well how am i going to add up the other values without count the already value from diagonal??

Comment: @KostasMatrix See my answer, which accomplishes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), a diagonally dominant matrix is a matrix such that:

> for every row of the matrix, the magnitude of the diagonal entry in a row is larger than or equal to the sum of the magnitudes of all the other (non-diagonal) entries in that row.

This just checks for weak diagonal dominance, given a 2D array:

```
public boolean isDiagonallyDominant(int[][] array) {
    int otherTotal = 0;

    // Loop through every row in the array
    for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        otherTotal = 0;

        // Loop through every element in the row
        for(int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++) {

            // If this element is NOT on the diagonal
            if(column != row) {

                // Add it to the running total
                otherTotal += Math.abs(array[row][column]);
            }
        }

        // If this diagonal element is LESS than the sum of the other ones...
        if(Math.abs(array[row][row]) < otherTotal) {

            // then the array isn't diagonally dominant and we can return.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Turing85 Fixed. Thank you for spotting that!

Answer (score 2):

In theory: in the i-th row, check that the i-th entry is smaller than the sum of the absolute values of the other values of the row:

```
public boolean checkDominance(int[][] matrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i)
    {
        int diagEl = Math.abs(matrix[i][i]);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].lenght; ++j)
        {
            if (i == j) { continue; }
            sum += Math.abs(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        if (sum > diagEl) { return (false); }
    }
    return (true);
}
```